# What does ‘common carrier obligations and duties mean’?

Tags: antitrust-law

[Lina Khan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lina_Khan) whilst still a law student at Yale Law School published an article in Yale Law Journal on applying competition law to Amazon titled *Amazons Anti-Trust Paradox*. The New York Times described it as:

> Reframing decades of monopoly law

It was also picked up by *Foreign Policy Magazine* where they noted:

> She argues that Amazon’s market dominance and its accumulation of user data demonstrated a need for the US to urgently update its anti-trust law for the era of tech giants. The paper got more than 140,000 hits and Khan was suddenly a legal celebrity. In July 2018 she joined the Federal Commission as the agency stepped up its scrutiny of tech giants.

In the Wikipedia article linked above, they say that she proposes that:

> Restoring traditional anti-trust and competition policy principles or applying common carrier obligations and duties.

What does ‘applying common carrier obligations and duties’ mean in relation, say, to Facebook?